# How to add element to the beginning of the store

Tags: sencha-touch-2

The add method adds the menuPoint to the end of the store, how can I add it to the beginning instead?
Have gone through all methods in the store documentation, but cant find a method putting the element to the beginning of the store.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.Store

```
var store =  Ext.getStore('AdultMenuStore');//adultmenulist.getStore();
    for(var i=0; i < adultObj.children.length; i++){
    var child = adultObj.children[i];
    var menuPoint = Ext.create('Sencha.model.MenuPoint', 
        {
            id: child.childId, 
            name: child.firstName, 
            icon_url: 'http://kidsparent.no/images/adultMenu/bkids-home-profile.png', xtype: 'childmenu'
        });
        store.add(menuPoint);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `insert` method instead:

```
insert( Number index, Ext.data.Model[] records )
```